# I am having String values in x-axis and integer values in y-axis Using nvd3 how to plot the graph

Tags: nvd3.js

How to plot the stackedarea chart using x-axis as string values and y-axis should be number using nvd3
ex:-

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        "key": "2016-2017",
        "values": [['Cse', 100], ['ECE', 200], ['IT', 85], ['EEE', 65]]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you just do:

```
$scope.x = function(d) {
  return d[0];
}

$scope.y = function(d) {
  //coerce to number
  return +d[1];
}
```